# how to customize vim-rails to make :A go from vendor to spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, neovim

I was able to customize controller to go to request spec a long time ago.

recently joined a project where we have multiple engines placed in the vendor directory.

I have this snippet going

```
let g:rails_projections = {
      \  "app/controllers/*_controller.rb": {
      \      "test": [
      \        "spec/requests/{}_spec.rb",
      \        "spec/controllers/{}_controller_spec.rb",
      \        "test/controllers/{}_controller_test.rb"
      \      ],
      \      "alternate": [
      \        "spec/requests/{}_spec.rb",
      \        "spec/controllers/{}_controller_spec.rb",
      \        "test/controllers/{}_controller_test.rb"
      \      ],
      \   },
>>>>>>      \   "vendor/gems/courses/app/models/courses/{}.rb": {
>>>>>>      \      "alternate": "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/*_spec.rb"
>>>>>>      \      "test": "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/*_spec.rb",
>>>>>       \   },
      \   "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/*_spec.rb": {
      \      "alternate": "vendor/gems/courses/app/models/courses/{}.rb",
      \      "template": "require 'rails_helper'\n\n" .
      \        "RSpec.describe '{}' do\nend",
      \   },
      \ }
```

first and third sections work, but the middle doesn't. it seems to not recognize whatever I put in that block.

It works jumping from spec to model, but not from a model (withing engine) to spec.  no matter what I try the place, where it looks for test file, doesn't change.

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it out.

```
let g:rails_projections = {
  \  "vendor/gems/courses/app/models/courses/*.rb": {
  \      "test": [
  \        "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/{}_spec.rb",
  \      ],
  \      "alternate": [
  \        "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/{}_spec.rb",
  \      ],
  \   },
  \   "spec/vendor/gems/courses/models/*_spec.rb": {
  \      "alternate": "vendor/gems/courses/app/models/courses/{}.rb",
  \      "template": "require 'rails_helper'\n\n" .
  \        "RSpec.describe '{}' do\nend",
  \   },
  \ }
```

notice the subtle difference between `*.rb` and `{}.rb`

use `*.rb` in specifying the current path (where from), and `{}_spec.rb` in specifying alternate path (where to)